# Problemas al guardar una imagen con PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

No consigo guardar mi imagen al darle click en el menú de `guardar`. Busqué y lo que encontré fue la función : `Image.save`. Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk    
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Canvas
from tkinter import NW
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from sys import argv
import tkinter as tk

def guardar():
    global imagen
    ventana.filename=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="C:/User/Imágenes")
    ruta=ventana.filename
    imagen = Image.save(ruta)
    imagenL = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=imagenL)
```

Comment: Airan he editado la pregunta pero te recomiendo que revises el identado del código, no tengo claro que partes van fuera y que partes dentro de la función. Así mismo considera agregar un [mcve], por ejemplo que es exactamente la variable global `imagen` o que pretendes hacer con  `imagen = Image.save(ruta)`,  `Image.save` retorna `None`... Para formatear tu código solo tienes que copiarlo, luego lo seleccionas y puslsas Ctrl + k o el botón `{}` del editor. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la observación y recomendación,la variable global imagen va a contener mi  imagen  y por lo que investigue  Image.save ,guarda la imagen.Ya puedo extraer una imagen desde mi galería ,pero esa misma la quiero guardar en una ruta especificada ,es lo que no me queda.Espero haberme dado a entender en lo que hice.

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema podría estar en la ruta de la imagen.

prueba esto:

no uses "." en "ventana.filename" mejor usa "_" y haslo asi:

```
with open(ventana_filename,"r")as arc:
    ruta = arc.read()
```